# Incrementing time by a specified interval using joda library

Tags: java, jodatime

```
 public Map<Integer , String> Timeinterval(int value)
    {
    int i = 1440/value ;
    Map<Integer, String> timeInt = new HashMap<Integer, String>() ;
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = null ;
    for(int a=0 ; a< i ; a++)
    {
    formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm");
    LocalTime time = formatter.parseLocalTime("09:00");
    time = time.plusMinutes(value);

    timeInt.put(a,time.toString() );
    }

    return timeInt;
    }
```

The argument value gets it value from JSP at runtime

The moment the control reaches at `formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm")` it could not go beyond this.
I executed this part `DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm")` by pressing cntrl+shift+I and got this message:

> could not resolve type: org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat

Let me know if anything else is wrong with the code

Basically what I want to do is increment time for eg: if time is 09:00 and I want to increment it by 30 then it should become 09:30 and this goes on till the time loop condition is satisfied. When I researched on net, I found out that Joda library is easier to work with for such tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clean. The `LocalTime` of Joda time does support the [`plusMinutes(int)`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html#plusMinutes%28int%29) which is exactly what you are looking for.

Of course you need to set the time outside the loop:

```
Map<Integer, String> timeInterval(int perDay)
{
    int minutes = 1440/perDay ;
    Map<Integer, String> timeInt = new HashMap<Integer, String>() ;
    LocalTime time =  DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm").parseLocalTime("09:00");

    for(int i=0; i < perDay; i++) {
        timeInt.put(i,time.toString());
        time = time.plusMinutes(minutes);
    }

    return timeInt;
}
```

Comment: I executed this code but same thing happened control cannot go beyond LocalTime time =  DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm").parseLocalTime("09:00");   . It again says could not resolve type: org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat on press of cntrl +shift + I .

Comment: Execute? You mean it compiles or it does not compile? If your IDE cannot find the type in the cimpletion you might have a wrong or missing joda time JAR file configured.

Comment: I am using Eclipse Kepler ,and I am comipling my project thru ANT ,but I am unable to execute after  line -LocalTime time =  DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm").parseLocalTime("09:00"); .

Comment: define "execute". Do you mean in the debugger? Does it print an exception? Or do you mean compile error? Or do you mean the editor does not allow to type it?

Comment: Excute  means at the time of debugging the code ,,I am able to compile and Type it in editor perfectly .When the debugger reaches here LocalTime time =  DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm").parseLocalTime("09:00"); ,it can't go any further ,when I excute this current line by pressing cntrl+shft+i it says could not resolve type: org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat and when i debug further by pressing F6 then new page opens saying class file editor -Source not found

Comment: I guess you get an exception because it cannot load the Joda Time classes because it misses the JAR in the classpath of the execution. You can add libraries to the run or debug configuration (not sure if it inherits it from the build path when you use ant, but it looks like it does not). Besides: try to start it without the debugger, it might show the exception more prominent. Hm, ctrl+shift+i means inspect? Might be a problem that joda.jar ha no debug info. Just use good old System.out then.

Comment: Dont you think ,,if it misses the JAR then I would not have been able to type in editor itself ,it would have shown some error,what say ????

Comment: No I don't think, the build and run configurations are different.